# I am trying to deploy an application using webpack onto Heroku. application works locally but on heroku, receiving error : sh: 1: webpack: not found

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

I am trying to deploy a simple Text Editor Application on Heroku. The application seems to work locally, but heroku does not seem to recognize the term `webpack` this could refer to my client/package.json. below you will find how my package.json(s) have been formatted and my heroku deploy error.

**ROOT package.json****

```
{
  "name": "JATE",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "concurrently \"cd client && npm run build\" \"cd server && npm run server\" ",
    "start": "npm run build && cd server && node server.js",
    "server": "cd server node server.js --ignore client",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install": "cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "heroku-prebuild": "npm install --dev"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "if-env": "^1.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

**MY client/package.json**

```
{
  "name": "JATE",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack --watch"
    
  },
  "author": "2U",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.51.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-pwa-manifest": "^4.3.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "code-mirror-themes": "^1.0.0",
    "idb": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

**My server/package.json**

```
{
    "name": "JATE",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "server": "nodemon server.js --ignore client"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
    }
}
```

**Here is my Heroku logs**

> ```
> remote: Building source:
> remote: 
> remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
> remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
> remote: -----> Node.js app detected
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
> remote:
> remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
> remote:        USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
> remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
> remote:        NODE_ENV=production
> remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
> remote:
> remote: -----> Installing binaries
> remote:        engines.node (package.json):  18.x
> remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
> remote:
> remote:        Resolving node version 18.x...
> remote:        Downloading and installing node 18.15.0...
> remote:        Using default npm version: 9.5.0
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Prebuild
> remote:        Running heroku-prebuild
> remote:        
> remote:        > JATE@1.0.0 heroku-prebuild
> remote:        > npm install --dev
> remote:
> remote:        
> remote:        > JATE@1.0.0 install
> remote:        > cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
> remote:
> remote:        
> remote:        added 57 packages, and audited 58 packages in 440ms
> remote:
> remote:        7 packages are looking for funding
> remote:          run `npm fund` for details
> remote:
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
> remote:        
> remote:        added 2 packages, and audited 3 packages in 1s
> remote:
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
> remote:        
> remote:        added 162 packages, and audited 163 packages in 13s
> remote:
> remote:        16 packages are looking for funding
> remote:          run `npm fund` for details
> remote:
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
> remote: npm notice
> remote: npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.5.0 -> 9.6.2
> remote: npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.6.2>
> remote: npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.6.2` to update!
> remote: npm notice
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Installing dependencies
> remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
> remote:        
> remote:        > JATE@1.0.0 install
> remote:        > cd server && npm i && cd ../client && npm i
> remote:
> remote:        
> remote:        up to date, audited 58 packages in 372ms
> remote:
> remote:        7 packages are looking for funding
> remote:          run `npm fund` for details
> remote:
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
> remote:        
> remote:        up to date, audited 3 packages in 1s
> remote:
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
> remote:        
> remote:        up to date, audited 163 packages in 3s
> remote:
> remote:        16 packages are looking for funding
> remote:          run `npm fund` for details
> remote:
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
> remote:        
> remote: -----> Build
> remote:        Running build
> remote:        
> remote:        > JATE@1.0.0 build
> remote:        > cd client && npm run build
> remote:
> remote:        
> remote:        > build
> remote:        > webpack --mode production
> remote:
> remote: sh: 1: webpack: not found
> remote: 
> remote: -----> Build failed
> remote:        
> remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
> remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
> remote:
> remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
> remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
> remote:
> remote:        Love,
> remote:        Heroku
> remote:
> remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
> remote: 
> remote:  !     Push failed
> remote: Verifying deploy...
> remote:
> remote: !       Push rejected to murmuring-headland-78036.
> remote:
> To https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-headland-78036.git
> [remote rejected]   main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/murmuring-headland-78036.git'
> ```

Some common solutions/methods i have tried

- heroku buildpack/nodejs is installed
- heroku config use_npm_install=true
- deployed both on cli and github on heroku

still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally deploy to heroku after adding a heroku config line on Heroku CLI or in my case VSCODE TERMINAL.

Using `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` will skip/ignore the dev dependencies because it is in production.

**However**, I did try this solution way earlier on the heroku application settings via config vars where `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` is the key and `false` is the value and it did not not seem to work. but using heroku CLI/VScode terminal worked for me.